# Algorithm spanning more than one page

Tags: algorithms, line-numbering

I have an algorithm which is too long to fit on one page. Someone suggested splitting the algortithm manually and then altering the second algorithm's line numbers to follow on the first. I know `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` numbers every line, whereas `\begin{algorithmic}[5]` numbers every fifth. How to I change the starting number from "1" to something else?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. `:)`

Comment: Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) or any information what packages you use to create your algorithms it's hard to say.

Answer (score 9):

The following minimal example shows how to modify the starting line number for an algorithm. Within the `algorithmic` environment, add the code

```
\makeatletter\setcounter{ALG@line}{<n>}\makeatother
```

where `<n>` is one smaller than the first line number. The reason for this is because the `\State` command increments the counter first, before typesetting it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \makeatletter\setcounter{ALG@line}{5}\makeatother
  \State Here is some code
  \State Here is another line of code
  \State And then some more
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This, of course, assumes that you're using the (more advanced) [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) to typeset your `algorithmic` environments.

If you would like to make this procedure a little more convenient, it is possible. For example, you can redefine `\State` to do this for you by providing an optional command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\let\oldState\State% Store \State in \oldState
\RenewDocumentCommand{\State}{o}{% \State[<num>]
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\makeatletter\setcounter{ALG@line}{#1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}\makeatother}{}%
  \oldState\ignorespaces%
}%
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State[8] Here is some code
  \State Here is another line of code
  \State And then some more
  \State[5] and a last line of code
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The interface for redefining `\State` to `\State[<num>]` is provided by [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse).

Note that if you plan on breaking up a single `algorithmic` environment across more than one page, `algorithmicx` also offers `\algstore{<name>}` and `\algrestore{<name>}` options. Here's a short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State Here is some code
  \State Here is another line of code
  \algstore{myalg}% Save algorithm
\end{algorithmic}

\hrule

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \algrestore{myalg}% Restore algorithm
  \State And then some more
  \State and a last line of code
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]